# How to convert Timestamp in UTC time using AWK

Tags: ubuntu, awk, utc, strftime

I try to process a mail log file using awk, but I have an issue with the conversion of the Timestamp into an UTC format.

The Input file looks like :

```
# cat /tmp/TimeStamps1.tmp

2016-08-10T00:23:45.984558+02:00
2016-09-30T10:23:45.984558+02:00
2016-10-31T20:45:27.984558+01:00
```

And the expect output should be :

```
cat /tmp/Target

2016-08-09 22:23:45
2016-09-30 08:23:45
2016-10-31 19:45:27
```

As the "T" between Date & Time seems an issue, I also tried to remove it :

```
# cat /tmp/TimeStamps2.tmp

2016-08-10 00:23:45.984558+02:00
2016-09-30 10:23:45.984558+02:00
2016-10-31 20:45:27.984558+01:00
```

First try using system()

```
awk ' {print $1" - "system("date -u +%Y-%m-%d -d" $0) } ' /tmp/TimeStamps2.tmp
date: extra operand `00:23:45.984558+02:00'
Try `date --help' for more information.
2016-08-10 - 1
date: extra operand `10:23:45.984558+02:00'
Try `date --help' for more information.
2016-09-30 - 1
date: extra operand `20:45:27.984558+01:00'
Try `date --help' for more information.
2016-10-31 - 1
```

Second try using strftime()

```
/tmp$ awk -F',' ' {print $1" - "strftime( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", $1)} ' /tmp/TimeStamps2.tmp
2016-08-10 00:23:45.984558+02:00 - 1970-01-01 01:33:36
2016-09-30 10:23:45.984558+02:00 - 1970-01-01 01:33:36
2016-10-31 20:45:27.984558+01:00 - 1970-01-01 01:33:36
```

Comment: date is working find:

    date -u +%Y-%m-%d' '%T -d"2016-08-10 00:23:45.984558+02:00"
2016-08-09 22:23:45

Comment: No problem to use GAWK, strftime and mktime are available. 
The format of the argument expect by mktime is is a string of the form "YYYY MM DD HH MM SS [DST]".
I will have to try to reformat accordingly, any suggestion for [DST] format ?

Comment: This is providing a good results : echo "2016-08-10 00:23:45.984558+02:00" | awk -F',' -v sep=\" ' {  system("date -u +%Y-%m-%dT-%T -d" sep $1 sep ) } ' 

2016-08-09T-22:23:45
I have to had the "T" within the format, the space is causing problem.

Comment: awk   ' {  system("date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T -d" \""  $1  \"" );  } ' TimeStamps2.tmp


awk:  {  system("date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T -d" \""  $1  \"" );  }
awk:                                      ^ backslash not last character on line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It now sounds like this is what you're really trying to do:

```
$ cat file
2016-08-10T00:23:45.984558+02:00 here is the first line
2016-09-30T10:23:45.984558+02:00 and here's the second
2016-10-31T20:45:27.984558+01:00 oh look, a third!

$ awk '{
    ts=$1; sub(/T/," ",ts); sub(/[^ ]+ /,"")
    cmd="date -u +\"%Y-%m-%d %T\" -d \"" ts "\""
    if ((cmd | getline line) > 0) {
        print line, $0
    }
    close(cmd)
}' file
2016-08-09 22:23:45 here is the first line
2016-09-30 08:23:45 and here's the second
2016-10-31 19:45:27 oh look, a third!
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a first answer, thx to  Ed Morton !

```
awk ' { A=$1" "$2;system("date -u +%Y-%m-%d\" \"%T -d \""A"\""  ); } ' TimeStamps2.tmp
2016-08-09 22:23:45
2016-09-30 08:23:45
2016-10-31 19:45:27
```

Comment: Try `"date -u +\"%Y-%m-%d %T\" -d \""A"\""` instead. It's more reasonable/common/readable to quote a whole string rather than individual spaces within it: `"foo bar"` rather than `foo" "bar`.

Comment: Indeed, many thanks.
I noted that the result of the system() command is not available in the awk script, if I try to convert a mail.log file, only the timestamp will be available as output :(

Comment: Right, `system(cmd)` is not how you do that, `cmd | getline` is. That takes us back to one of the first comments you got which was to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output so we could help you do whatever it is you're really trying to do rather than just helping you implement what you think you need to implement.